# Get IP address from Android and IOS Device using .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, ip-address, .net-maui

I am trying to get IP address from android device using .NET MAUI. (Current android framework net6.0-android)

With the below code, I can get the IP with the first launch of the application. And it does not work with following launch of the application unless I reboot my phone.(Tested on Samsung S10+ Android 12)

```
    private void GetIPAddressClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string interfaceDescription = string.Empty;
    var result = new List<IPAddress>();
    try
    {
        var upAndNotLoopbackNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(n => n.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback
                                                                                                      && n.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up);

        foreach (var networkInterface in upAndNotLoopbackNetworkInterfaces)
        {
            var iPInterfaceProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();

            var unicastIpAddressInformation = iPInterfaceProperties.UnicastAddresses.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            if (unicastIpAddressInformation == null) continue;

            result.Add(unicastIpAddressInformation.Address);

            interfaceDescription += networkInterface.Description + "---";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to find IP: {ex.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        string allIpInfo = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            allIpInfo += item.ToString() + "---";
        }
        IPAddress.Text = allIpInfo;

        InterfaceName.Text = interfaceDescription;
    }
```

When it works,

interfaceDescription  = "------"

allIpInfo = "192.168.50.112---127.0.0.1---"

When it does not work,

interfaceDescription   ---> rmnet_data0

allIpInfo ---> 192.0.0.2

I am not sure what is wrong here. How can I fix this? Or is there a better way to get the IP address?
Thanks.

Comment: You can try it with other devices.

Comment: It works for me, almost in Android

Comment: for me works, Im using a Samsung Tablet with Android 13. I don't interfaceDescription.

Answer (score 2):

In alternativa, I can recommend this method. It returns only the IP address and not the entire list like in the code above.

Import these libraries

```
#if ANDROID
using Android.App;
using Android.Net.Wifi;
#endif
```

And use this code

```
var result = "";
#if ANDROID
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Service.WifiService);
            int ipaddress = wifiManager.ConnectionInfo.IpAddress;
            IPAddress ipAddr = new IPAddress(ipaddress);  
            result = ipAddr.ToString();
#endif
```

For Windows u can use

```
var result = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToString();
```

Comment: in the case of  "OutOfRangeException" (maybe a bug in java), try this:

`byte[] ipaddress = BitConverter.GetBytes(wifiManager.ConnectionInfo.IpAddreess);
// the byte array contain: byte[4] = [ 192 ,168 ,12, 135 ];
result = (new IPAddress(ipaddress)).ToString();`