# .NET MAUI how to obtain Wifi/Connected network ip address of the device on iOs and Android?

Tags: android, ios, networking, maui

How do we get the local device IP address (not the external IP address) in [.NET MAUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin#.NET_MAUI) on platforms iOS and Android?

The following answer specifies a solution for Android by using WifiManager.ConnectionInfo which Visual Studio clearly warns that the WifiManager.ConnectionInfo is obsoleted on Android 31 and higher;

[Get IP address from Android and IOS Device using .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72511486/get-ip-address-from-android-and-ios-device-using-net-maui)

And the following GitHub page provides an example for iOS using NSNetService.Addresses. Again, Visual Studio states that NSNetService.Addresses is obsoleted on iOS 15 and higher and recommends using Network framework, but the documentation is mess and there aren't any examples available;

https://gist.github.com/jbe2277/4b9f5ac0fb3556569960d2e1f3c5bf28

Comment: Why do you want the local ip addresses?  You should read this https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734295

Comment: @Paulw11 local IP address is required so app can scan local network for a specific device.

Comment: If you control the device firmware it is strongly recommended that you support ipv6 and Bonjour. Scanning an entire network will be difficult on larger networks and impossible on pure ipv6 networks.

Comment: @Paulw11 Unfortunately I do not have any jurisdiction on the aforementioned device's firmware, as it is a 3rd party closed sourced device.

Comment: See "Service Discovery" in the document I linked to.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for your time, I have already checked the source you've shared. SSDP is out of question for the project I am working on due to device does not broadcast any kind of information, aside from having very few end-points for a limited rest API.

Comment: Then you are probably going to find it difficult on both iOS and Android for the reasons outlined in the developer thread. Networking is complex. [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734338) is the suggested approach on ios. It uses BSD APIs so it may be somewhat applicable to Android as well as it has Unix at its core.

Comment: @OnurBuyukcaglar ConnectionInfo is deprecated, but it is replaced by connectivity manager.